# Smooth endles scrolling background with canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Welcome all

I have a background image and what I want is for it to be moving slowly to the right and when the image has reach the right end of the screen with the end of the left starting side of the image, the image must start again showing the start of the right side, as an infinite horizontal scroll.

How can this be achieved without generating bitmap overflow memory exceptions?

I tryed it drawing two times the bitmap with canvas... but it is not smooth, it is very creepy with jumps and not optimized:

```
universeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(universeBitmap, sw, sh, false); 

    universeView = new View(this){

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (paused==true){
                canvas.drawBitmap(universeBitmap, universeX, 0, null);          
                return;
            }
            long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((currentTime-lastdrawTime)>100){                    
                if (universeX>sw){
                    universeX=0;
                }
                lastdrawTime=currentTime;
                universeX+=1;
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(universeBitmap, universeX, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(universeBitmap, universeX-sw, 0, null);
            invalidate();
        }   
    };
```

I also tried without invalidating the view each 100ms, but with a thread and a handler, and same result.... creepy non smooth movement:

```
universeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(universeBitmap, sw, sh, false); 

            universeView = new View(this){

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    super.onDraw(canvas);               
                    canvas.drawBitmap(universeBitmap, universeX, 0, null);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(universeBitmap, universeX-sw, 0, null);
                }   
            };
.
.
.
        Handler handler=new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (universeX>sw){
                    universeX=0;
                }
                universeView.invalidate();
                universeX+=1;
            }
        };  

.
.
.

     public void run() {
            try {
               while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
                   synchronized(this){  
                       handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);   
                       wait(100);
                   }    
               }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming you don't want for user to scroll this background by own you may use [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) with [INFINITE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode%28int%29) param for repeat mode, it will be smooth. create 2 `ImageView`s horizontally (or even simple `View`s and setting `Bitmap` as background) and move their parent. when first get off the screen remove it and add another on other side. this is for background photo/image filling whole screen, if you have other size background just add more `ImageView`s to create 2x or more summary length than width of the screen (which can be easly measured on in `onCreate` or wherever. Just create something like `Adapter` for background image or even you may tray existing projects/libs usually named smth like `HorizontalScrollView` with `Adapter` returning some large numer in `getCount`, e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

about `Bitmap` errors - note that `Adapter` don't destroy lost/lefting `View`s, but use them as next (recreates) - this is `convertView` in `getView(...)` method. use `ViewHolder` pattern and you will use only two `View`s with single `Bitmap` setting (same refrence). you may create just once your static background `Bitmap` in constructor and keep in [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) preventing from recycle it. every device can handle bitmap with same size as screen